# The book Probability Theory by Klenke, Exercise 1.2.1, I wonder if it’s an error?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

The book *Probability Theory* by Klenke has for Exercise 1.2.1 the following:

> Let $$A =\{(a,b]\cap \mathbb Q : \ a,b\in\mathbb R, \ a\le b\}.$$ Define $$\mu: A \to [0,\infty)$$ by $$ \mu((a,b]\cap \mathbb Q) =b−a.$$ Show that $A$ is a semiring and $\mu$ is a content on $A$ that is lower and upper semicontinuous but is not $\sigma$-additive.

I come to the conclusion that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.  Mostly because all my attempts to think of an example of failure to be $\sigma$-additive bear no fruit.

Can someone help me prove it one way or the other?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for typesetting math here.

Comment: Hint: enumerate the rationals, then for each rational that you haven't yet covered with an element of $A$, cover it with an element from $A$ less than half the measure of the previous element. You should end up with a countable set of disjoint elements of $A$ which between them cover all rationals, but have finite total measure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you fblundun and thank you Adam k.

Since $Q$ is countable, let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in (0, 1]\cap Q\in A$ for some countable sequence of $x_1,x_2,\ldots.$  Define $A_n=(x_n − 1/2^{n+1}, x_n] \cup Q\in A,\forall n$;
define $B_1= A_1$, $B_i = A_i \setminus \cup^{i−1}_{j=1}A_j,~i=1,2,\ldots n. $ Since $x_n\in A_n,~\forall n,\cup_i A_i= (0, 1]\cap Q$.

$$\mu(\cup_iB_i)=\mu(\cup_i A_i)=1.$$ However, $$\sum_i \mu(B_i)\leq \sum_i\mu(A_i)= \sum_i1/2^{i+1}=1/2.$$ Since
$\mu(\cup_iB_i)\neq\sum_i\mu(B_i)$, $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-additive.